# Snowflake to_date() function is not working properly for the FEB month

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, to-date

Snowflake to_date() function is converting an input expression to a wrong date.

```
select to_date('2019-02-29', 'yyyymmdd')
2019-03-01
```

```
select to_date('2019-02-30', 'yyyymmdd')
2019-03-02
```

```
select to_date('2019-02-31', 'yyyymmdd')
2019-03-03
```

```
select to_date('2019-02-32', 'yyyymmdd')
Can't parse '2019-02-32' as date with format 'yyyymmdd'
```

Comment: None of those are real dates. February has only 28 days in the year 2019. It's doing its best to work with the garbage you are feeding it, which is really pretty admirable as I would imagine most rdbms would just throw an error if you tried to pull this off.

Comment: @JNevill Yes correct those are invalid dates. For '2019-02-32' it is throwing an error but for '2019-02-31' it is converting to the wrong date.

Comment: I read that last one where it throws the error, and then I ate my words... I agree that the most consistent and reasonable response from the database would be an error in all of these cases. The bit I've worked with snowflake, I've noticed that it's flaky with dates.

Comment: postgres 11.2 gives `2019-01-02` for all 4 of this inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I think (opinion) the original intent was to try to help folks load data, in a "just get it in" kind of fashion.

Coming to an account near you soon - Snowflake will be enforcing this much more strictly, details here:
https://support.snowflake.net/s/article/SQL-Changes-to-String-to-Date-Conversion-Pending

and if you can't get into the old lodge, here's a cached version from Google:

https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:TYy0mikXecoJ:https://support.snowflake.net/s/article/SQL-Changes-to-String-to-Date-Conversion-Pending+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

For testing, you might try the TRY_TO_DATE() function, here are the docs for to_date() and try_to_date() for you to review.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/try_to_date.html

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/to_date.html

Comment: BEWARE! Both of these functions will also interpret an integer, like '123', as a date value! The usage notes on to_date() explain this.